# Site Stuck in Maintenance Mode

Tags: maintenance

My site is stuck with the `site undergoing maintenance`-error.  The usually fixes have not worked (no `.maintenance` file to delete, plugins all check out)

It seems that it is a problem with the theme but the developer says that it all checks out.

I've tried several installs of wordpress and the theme, many hours with host also.

Comment: to claer it see instructions in this WP codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_to_clear_the_.22Briefly_unavailable_for_scheduled_maintenance.22_message_after_doing_automatic_upgrade.3F

Comment: One more important note. The site loads if I'm logged in as the admin. If I'm not logged in the site shows the error..

Comment: Thanks Tara- That fix recommends deleting the .maintenance file and I do not have one.

Comment: How did the site get put into maintenance mode? Note that "dot" files-- files that begin with a period-- are considered configuration files by some OSes (Linux in particular) and are hidden by default. Some FTP software also hides those files, or needs to be told to show them. Are you sure that there is no `.maintenance` file? And not one that is just hidden from view?

Comment: To show "hidden" files (that start with a "dot"/`.` and therefore the file gets treated as "no name, extension only") on the command line/terminal, you can use `ls -laG` to show them as well. Also make sure to test with a different theme to see if the theme is the root of this problem.

Answer (score 4):

WordPress creates a `.maintenance` file during the update process which indicates that your site is in the maintenance mode. Unless this file is removed your site will remain in the maintenance mode and your users will continue to see the notification.

Once you have updated WordPress, all you have to do is delete `.maintenance` file from your site’s root folder using FTP.

If you can not see `.maintenance` file in your site’s root directory, then make sure you checked your FTP client to show hidden files. In Filezilla, you can force it to show hidden files by clicking on *Server **»** Force showing hidden files* from the menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

Try manually creating and then deleting the .maintenance file (this has worked for me once):

```
 echo "something" > .maintenance
 rm .maintenance
```

Comment: Please add more explanation on how to use the solution.

Answer (score 1):

run the wp-activate.php script, worked for me.